# Use of &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp; in query strings

Tags: php, html

I am following [this](http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration) tutorial about integrating Paypal in one's website.
Many times in the page, at **line 20** of **step 3** for example, I find this:

```
if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp; !isset($_POST["txn_type"])){
```

I really don't understand the use of `&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;` in the query strings.
The language used is PHP/HTML

Comment: I'm fairly sure someone messed up the HTML escaping, and that it should be just `&&`.

Answer (score 3):

That's not intentionally kept by the developer. The `&` characters are converted into the `&amp;` by some kind of plugin/scripts while formatting the code.

Looking at the code you should have this:

```
if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])){
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem in whatever software they're using to encode the text of the article. It's a good reason to preserve input text and encode for different contexts.

It should simply be `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found a real solution but this chain is written in Wordpress documentation, here :
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

++ Nicolas.